# Sockets code in Rakudo Perl

Tags: perl, raku, rakudo, rakudo-star

I've been trying to run some sockets code in Rakudo Perl (freshly built from the repository at http://github.com/rakudo/rakudo) but the implementation of [IO::Socket::INET](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Socket::INET) appears to be incomplete.

The code I'm trying to run is here: http://github.com/carlins/irc-client/blob/master/lib/IRC/Client.pm

This is the error:

```
    Method 'input-line-separator' not found for invocant of class 'IO;Socket;INET'
      in 'IRC::Client::connect' at line 30:lib/IRC/Client.pm
      in main program body at line 13:example.pl
```

The same thing happens with Rakudo Star, built from the official tarball. Pointers?

Comment: All this code is very new; I expect that patches would be gratefully accepted :)

Answer (score 5):

The IRC::Client code is quite old now (look at the last commits) and it's quite probable it'll simply not work with current Rakudo. You may try the old alpha branch if you really want to try, there is plenty of old Perl 6 code which runs well on it.

About IO::Socket::INET, I don't really think it's incomplete or anything, the case you've shown is about IRC::Client directly. And as I said, Rakudo and even Perl 6 is still evolving and it's possible that something has changed about them.

Comment: I took a look at the IO::Socket::INET module in the Rakudo source tree. It *is* incomplete. In fact, someone on #perl6 said I was free to flesh it out if I wanted to.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a nice Weekend Project to me :)